# How to filter dangerous chars in a bash script?

Tags: performance, bash, security, shell, validation

I'm working in a project that uses a massive amount of shellscripts for all kind of purposes, and the performance and portability are important. Some of these scripts are using configuration files, that have the following format:

```
VARIABLE1="value"
VARIABLE2="several words, several values"
VARIABLE3="a,list,of,words"
```

Then, to use these variables we just need to tdo the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /path/to/the/configuration.file

echo "Var 1 is: $VARIABLE1"
echo "Var 2 is: $VARIABLE2"
echo "Var 3 is: $VARIABLE3"
```

Simple, right?

Not so much. The fact is that while we can protect the scripts against modification with a simple `chown root file.sh; chmod 0711 file.sh`, the configuration files must be writable, and then we find out that nasty things like this can happen:

```
VARIABLE1="value"; rm requiredfile.data
VARIABLE2="you dont want to see this: `rm anotherimportantfile.data`
rm thelastrequiredfile.bin
```

So when the configuration file is invoked, the instructions inserted in it will be **executed with the privileges of any user that actually invokes it**.

I know what I'm asking is tricky, but I would like to be able to filter all dangerous syntax that can lead to unauthorized code execution.

What I've done so far:

```
FILTER='
/^$/d                                # Delete empty lines
/^#/d                                # Delete comments
/^[A-Z0-9_]\+=.\+$/{                 # Select assignments
/`/p                                 # alert with `
/\$/p                                # alert with $
/\\/p                                # alert with \ 
/;/p                                 # alert with ;
d                                    # Accept the rest
}
'
C=`sed -e "$FILTER" $1 | wc -l` 2>/dev/null
if test $C -gt 0; then
   echo "#ERR Suspicious strings in configuration file"
fi
```

What am I missing? Any improvements?

PS: I know that it could be possible to read safely each variable with a `grep`/`cut` combination, but it's out of the question for performance issues.

Comment: For a start you're missing the bashism `$(...)` which is the equivalent of `\`...\``.

Comment: Thank you, @Phylogenesis. I forgot that one. Adding it.

Comment: @JakubJirutka not only performance is a key, also portability between platforms with different architectures. Take it as a desing constraint :)

Comment: @opalenzuela There are plenty of portable interpreted languages with better performance, e.g. Python, Perl or even Groovy. Doing everything in Bash is insane.

Comment: Again, this is a design constraint. We are already using other technologies for heavy algorithms. This requirement affects only the higher layer of the whole system.

Comment: What about robustness?  The system could be caused to abort by putting `set -e` or other funny -- by themselves legitimate -- Bash constructs in a file which will get sourced.  What about `${unset_variable?Gotcha}`?  What about masking out required settings with an unpaired quote or a here document?

Comment: Those aren't even really dangerous like [](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F4A9/index.htm)

Comment: @tripleee `${unset_variable?Gotcha}` would be already filtered by the `$` character, right?

Comment: Right, missed that.  So your variables cannot refer to other variables?  That's unfortunate, too.

Comment: What about  `sleep 4294967296`?

Comment: @tripleee  what about it? :) It won't pass if the line does not have a "=" character following the variable name.

Comment: `FNORD= sleep 4294967296` passes.  You can try to tighten your regexes but it's a lost battle IMHO.

Comment: Allowing whitespace around the equals sign is a mistake, though.  Shell syntax does not allow for whitespace, as the previous example incidentally illustrates.

Answer (score 5):

An often cited security paradigm is that you should enumerate the permitted patterns, not try to enumerate all the possible disallowed patterns.

If you restrict yourself to variables being assigned values that are always single-quoted strings, the only pattern you have to allow is

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*='[^']*'[\t ]*$
```

The trailing whitespace isn't strictly necessary (and if you want to be nice, you could allow for leading whitespace as well).

Single quotes inhibit all shell metacharacters; any string in single quotes is taken verbatim.

Allowing double quotes or unquoted strings is simply inviting trouble.  The transition to single quotes might be a bit of a hassle, but if you came here for security advice, that's what you'll get.

Incidentally, you can simply use `grep` to look for violations:

```
if grep -v "^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*='[^']*'[\t ]*$" configfile /dev/null >&2; then
    echo "$0: Invalid lines in configfile -- aborting" >&2
    exit 2
fi

. configfile
:
:
```

As a user, I would appreciate the diagnostic message to include the violations.  This also avoids the cumbersome detour via `wc -l`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the script with it. +1 to the first constructive answer.

Answer (score 2):

forget the filter. My understand for this question is, you shouldn't give the write/read permission on config file directly to someone. you should only assign sudo permission to one group, add related users into that group.

Comment: I'm tempted to +1 this suggestion although it doesn't properly answer the question.

Comment: True, it does not answer the question. Also, in one way or another, users will be able to modify the file contents, and by doing so, entering some harmful data into it. That's exactly what we are trying to detect (not to avoid).

Comment: This fixes the problem, by circumventing the *dangerous practice* outlined in the question. +1